# Why query params are not reaching the interface?

Tags: java, rest

I'am trying to send a request to a REST interface implemented with javax.ws.rs and give it some query params, but the query params do not reach the interface.

The sending side is implemented as folowing:

```
WebTarget target = webTarget.path("test").path("Testuser");
target.queryParam("a","a");

System.out.println(target.getUri());
Response response = target.request().get();
```

The interface:

```
@GET
@Path("test/{username}")
public void test(
        @PathParam("username") String username,
        @QueryParam("a") String a) {
    System.out.println("TEST here!");
    System.out.println("username: " + username);
    System.out.println("a: " + a);
}
```

The output on the sender side is the plain URL without any query parameter.

The output on the interface side is

```
TEST here!
username: Testuser
a: null
```

I'am not able to see, where my error is, and why the a is not recived in the interface.

Comment: "The output on the sender side is the plain URL without any query parameter." That should make it clear to you that the interface side is irrelevant. If you're not sending the query parameter, the interface clearly won't receive it. I suggest you remove the interface part entirely from your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're ignoring the result of the `queryParam` method. The method doesn't modify the existing instance - it returns a new one, just like `path` does. From the docs:

> Create a new WebTarget instance by configuring a query parameter on the URI of the current target instance.

Just change your code to:

```java
WebTarget target = webTarget.path("test").path("Testuser").queryParam("a", "a");
```